# draft js data flow examples

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I'm working on a react project where we are going to use a lot of forms, including fields with rich HTML. I searched for a while and stumbled upon draft-js. It seems very good, but I can't seem to find any good examples of how to use it from beginning to end. Most of what I find is how to modify the controls, but that is not what I am looking for. Its basic functionality is all I need at the moment.

I've got it up and working in my form, I have the controls I want, etc., but I just don't know where to go from there.

My structure looks like this:

```
<Root>
    <FormContainer>
        <FormBody>
            <DraftEditor1>
            <DraftEditor2>
        <FormFooter>
            <CancelButton>
            <SubmitButton>
```

I have looked into `EditorState`, `convertToRaw`, etc., but can't figure out how to access the `EditorState` from my submit event.

I'm a little new to react as well, but I am thinking that I should put a submit event on the `SubmitButton` in an `onClick handler` which is passed down from the `FormContainer`.

My `clickHandler` should then fire a `Redux Action` to save the data in the form.

But in that case, how do I access and convert the `EditorState` to the correct data format, especially considering that I have multiple `DraftEditors` in my form?

If you know of any great examples or tutorials out there, please let me know.

Comment: please add some code you have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I drafted a simple code that can give you an idea:

```
...

_handleSubmit() {
  // dispatch an action
  // or save to redux store
  const { draftEditor1, draftEditor2 } = this.state;
  this.props.handleSubmit(draftEditor1, draftEditor2);
}

render() {
    return (
      <FormContainer>
        <FormBody>
          <DraftEditor1 editorState={this.state.draftEditor1} onChange={this.onChange1}>
          <DraftEditor2 editorState={this.state.draftEditor2} onChange={this.onChange2}>
        </FormBody>
        <FormFooter>
          <CancelButton />
          <SubmitButton onClick={this._handleSubmit} />
        </FormFooter>
      </FormContainer>
    );
}
...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I won't be able to look into it for a day or two, but I'll let you know as soon as I have the time :)